# How to add a placeholder option in drop down list with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In a `<select>` input, we can add a disabled option as a placeholder:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    ...
</select>
```

But how can we add that disabled option in a `<select>` built by AngularJS, where `ng-options` are supplied from the controller?

```
<select class="month" id="month"
        ng-model="vm.month"
        ng-options="m for m in vm.months">  
</select>
```

Comment: you can still add `options` to select as you shown in your example

Answer (score 5):

My it is that easy! Thank you HarishR.

```
<select class="month" id="month"
        ng-model="vm.month"
        ng-options="m for m in vm.months">  
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
</select>
```

And we can even dynamically show/hide the placeholder option:

```
<select class="month" id="month"
        ng-model="vm.month"
        ng-options="m for m in vm.months">  
    <option value="" disabled selected ng-hide="vm.month">Select your option</option>
</select>
```